# How can I get this type of output?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have a question which can be done using loops. I need a little bit faster methodology.

Consider I have two arrays.

`let meanArray  = [20,20,15]
let RGBArray = [[12,15,20],[20,20,10],[5,3,2]]`

I need to do some operation, consider an addition.

Such that I have to add the [meanArray] elements to each index of [RGBArray].

The output should be

`Output: sumArray = [[32,35,35],[40,40,25],[25,23,17]]`

Using higher-order functions.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with faster here, maybe you could post your current code and explain why it is slow and/or if you have attempted anything yourself to improve performance.

Comment: Using “higher-order functions”  does not necessarily make the code faster.

Comment: I have an RGB array which has 225*3 values. This array to be calculated with some other sub-arrays. I have implemented using for loop, which is taking much time to do the calculations. I have expected the faster methodology which means in less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combinations of `map(_:)` and `zip(_:_:)` on `meanArray` and `RGBArray` like so,

```
let meanArray  = [20,20,15]
let RGBArray = [[12,15,20],[20,20,10],[5,3,2]]

let result = RGBArray.map { zip($0, meanArray).map(+) }
print(result) //[[32, 35, 35], [40, 40, 25], [25, 23, 17]]
```

Comment: Or just `map(+)` .